# C++ frameworks for distributed computer applications

Tags: c++, distributed-computing

I have a C++/MFC application ("MyApp") that has always run standalone, but which now needs to be run simultaneously on at least two PCs, and eventually on perhaps up to 20 PCs. What is desirable is:

- The system will be deployed with fixed PC names ("host1", "host2", etc) and IP addresses (192.168.1.[host number]) on an isolated network
- Turn on the first PC, and it will start all the others using wake-on-lan
- One or more instances of "MyApp" automatically start on each node, configure themselves, and do their stuff more-or-less independently (there is no critical inter-node communication once started)
- The first node in the system also hosts a user interface that provides some access to other nodes. Communication to/from the other nodes only occurs at the user's request, which is generally sporadic for normal users, and occasionally intense for users who have to test that new features are working as designed across the system.
- For simulation/test purposes, MyApp should also be able to be started on a specified subset of arbitrarily-named computers on a LAN.

The point of the last requirement is so that when trying to reproduce the problem that is occurring on a 20-PC system on the other side of the world, I don't have to find 20 PCs from somewhere and hook them up, I can instead start by (politely) stealing some spare CPU cycles from other PCs in my office.

I can imagine building this from the ground up in C++/MFC along these lines:

- write a new service that automatically starts with Windows, and which can start/stop instances of MyApp when it receives the corresponding command via the network, or when configured to automatically start MyApp in non-test deployments.
- have MyApp detect which node it is in the wider system, and if it is the first node, ensure all other nodes are turned on via wake-on-lan
- design and implement a communications protocol between the various local and remote services, and MyApp instances

This really seems quite basic, but also like it would be reinventing wheels if I did it from the ground up. So the central question is are there frameworks with C++ classes that make this kind of thing easy? What options should I investigate? And is referring to this as "distributed computing" misleading? What else would you call it? (Please suggest additional or different tags)